# user_dump_dest is there harm in putting this on a NAS

Tags: oracle, configuration

Is it correct to say that typically user_dump_dest is on a local drive?

If so, are there issues with mounting a NAS volume to both Unix and Windows and pointing user_dump_dest at that?

If so, what are they?

Are any issues worth not doing this in prod?

Comment: Please don't say you shouldn't trace in prod... everyone has had issues that cannot be reproduced in a lower environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run 9.2 instances with user_dump_dest on a NAS and never had a problem with it.

If you are concerned though, have oracle write them locally, then sync them across to your NAS and remove them from local, I've never needed to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, typically (and by default), user_dump_dest is on a local drive.  I wouldn't expect there are any specific issues with putting it on NAS; but it would have all the potential issues that any application might:  (1) If the NAS could not be reached, Oracle would not be able to write out user dump files, and (2) the write latency would be increased.  The latency issue is probably only important if you're doing large-scale tracing to diagnose performance issues, as the write latency would impact the timing measurements.  I would expect that if the NAS because unreachable and Oracle tried to write to it, it would silently fail.

I don't think I would do it unless space constraints on the local disk forced me to.  But generally the contents of this directory should be insignificant relative to your data.

Comment: even a local drive can be unreachable. The latency delta is something to consider when comparing results.

Comment: And so far as the reason... to enable developers access without having to go as far as getting them Unix accounts.

Comment: yes, a local drive could be unreachable -- but in general if that happens I would think you have much bigger problems than whether user trace files are being written out.